Running a query that overlaps 2 days
I have the following query:
SELECT DISTINCT date_format(timestamp, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:00.000Z') as times
FROM "mytable"
WHERE year = {{.Year}}
    AND month = {{.Month}}
    AND (day = {{.Day}} OR day = {{.Day}} + 1)
    AND timestamp >=  TIMESTAMP '{{.Start}}'
ORDER BY 1

However, I believe this query would break at the end of the month, plus there are months where February ends on 28th or 29th. What would be the correct query for the day portion of the query?
Also, we need to include the case where the two days overlap between the month and the year.

ORDER BY 1 <-- I wish people would stop doing this...

Why is this tagged with both MySQL and Postgres? You're either using one or the other (or something else entirely) - and they are not cross-compatible.

Why does your myTable have separate year/month/day columns instead of using a datetime-typed column? If your table has a bad design then you'll end-up with a bad query...

@Dai I've updated the tag to only include posgresql, and the reason that myTable has separate month, day and year columns it was done like that at the beginning so I just inherited this.

when this is a really bad design , you have to build a datetime and add one day and then break it again to be able to compare it BUT a better solution would be to pass a single datetime parameter to the query instead of the separate year month , day values let's call it paramdatetime,and you will be able to handle all cases with a  much simpler query:
SELECT DISTINCT date_format(timestamp, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:00.000Z') as times
FROM "mytable"
WHERE (year = year({{.paramdatetime}}) AND month = month({{.paramdatetime}}) AND (day = day({{.paramdatetime}}) ) 
   OR (year = year({{.paramdatetime}} + interval '1' day) AND month = month({{.paramdatetime}} + interval '1' day) AND (day = day({{.paramdatetime}} + interval '1' day) ) 

